# Xcode 10.1: "No such SwiftUI module"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using Macos Mojave and Xcode 10.1. I clone my project from github (I used Xcode 13 before) and change objectVersion to 50:

[image]

Then I can open this project in Xcode 10.1.

But I get an error: "No such 'SwiftUI' module"

[image]

What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI was introduced with Xcode 11 [See here](https:////https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes)

So Xcode 10.1 has no module SwiftUI. You need a higher version, upwards of Xcode 11